# Center div while transition runs looks choppy

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I have a div with an inner span with text. This inside span should be centered vertically and horizontally all the time:

**http://jsfiddle.net/QW4Wk/**

```
<div>
    <span>Text aligned center</span>
</div>
```

The div has a transition when the mouse is over, which changes its width and height.

```
div{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:black;
position:relative;
-webkit-transition:width 10s,height 10s;
}
span {
position:absolute;
color:white;
bottom:0;
right:0;
}
div:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
}
```

However in Chrome (at least) the text looks choppy while the transition is running. I guess this is because the transition goes 1 by 1px and therefor the "center style" has to go back and forward 1px.

Is there someway to fix this to look smoother, something like subpixel?
Thanks.

Comment: 10s as a transition is a **VEEERY** long time.

Comment: Just to make it more obvious

Comment: So what is the **actual** time? Is it choppy at the proper speed?

Comment: The actual time is 3 seconds, Which is choppy in my opinion (looks like it shakes): http://jsfiddle.net/QW4Wk/2/

Comment: I don't really see the problem here.  I edited your JSFiddle to make the animation faster and it gets MUCH smoother.  Just increase your speed.

Comment: Even 3 seconds is WAAY too slow.  You should use something more in the range of .5s to smooth it out

Comment: Do you want the inner span to grow and rearrange itself ? Or it can be of fixed dimensions ?

Comment: @john-manly This depends on each case. However the fact that the speed is shorter doesn't make the "problem" dissapear

Comment: @vals I'd prefer it to rearrange but if fixed dimension is the only way to smooth then I'd be ok

Answer (score 1):

try this for absolute centering the text..

```
span {
  margin: auto;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  height:10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

and of course lessen your transition speed.

Comment: Looks nicer this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply a different change to the span. a transform can be *subpixel*

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition:width 10s,height 10s;
}
span {
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    top:75px;
    left:50px;
    width: 100px;
    transition: -webkit-transform 10s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
div:hover{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}

div:hover span {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(999px) translate(25px, 25px);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QW4Wk/4/)